# Select null data when variable is null SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to pass in a variable into a stored procedure in SQL Server when its null it should return all the rows that are null.

I couldn't find anything that helped me.

If I pass in the null into variable it returns nothing because you need to say `IS NULL`

```
DECLARE @itemId INT = 5435
DECLARE @id INT = NULL

SELECT 
    rt.Id,
    'Received' as Type,
    rt.Quantity,
    rt.CuttingInstuctionId,
    rt.Date
FROM 
    ReceivingItemsTransactions rt
LEFT JOIN  
    Order ci ON rt.OrderId = ci.Id
WHERE
    rt.ItemId = @itemId 
    AND ci.PlannedProductionId = @id
```

I expect to get only the null rows in this scenario.

What would be an alternative to this?

Comment: Then it will return all of the rows. I only want the null rows

Comment: Ah misunderstood then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an OR condition to test for both

```
declare @itemId int = 5435
declare @plannedProdId int = null

SELECT rt.Id,
'Received' as Type,
rt.Quantity,
rt.CuttingInstuctionId,
rt.Date
FROM ReceivingItemsTransactions rt
left join CuttingInstructions ci
on rt.CuttingInstuctionId = ci.Id
where rt.ItemId = @itemId and 
(
   (ci.PlannedProductionId = @plannedProdId) 
OR (@plannedProdId IS NULL AND ci.PlannedProductionId IS NULL
)
```

Or you could use a union maybe?

```
declare @itemId int = 5435
declare @plannedProdId int = null

SELECT rt.Id,
'Received' as Type,
rt.Quantity,
rt.CuttingInstuctionId,
rt.Date
FROM ReceivingItemsTransactions rt
left join CuttingInstructions ci
on rt.CuttingInstuctionId = ci.Id
where rt.ItemId = @itemId and 
(ci.PlannedProductionId = @plannedProdId) 
UNION ALL
SELECT rt.Id,
'Received' as Type,
rt.Quantity,
rt.CuttingInstuctionId,
rt.Date
FROM ReceivingItemsTransactions rt
left join CuttingInstructions ci
on rt.CuttingInstuctionId = ci.Id
where rt.ItemId = @itemId and (@plannedProdId IS NULL AND ci.PlannedProductionId IS NULL)
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! I was stuck on this couldn't find anything similar

Comment: Be aware this **could** be slightly bad for performance. A union may perform better depending on your data and SQL settings, I'd profile both and check. If you want best performance you could use dynamic SQL to add the last clause and run that, but thats more complicated

Comment: The union is better for performance?It seems like double the first way

Comment: Its about the same. I have to try it on more data sets

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: @barryDev You may want to have a look at [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) for more about the performance issues and `option (recompile)`.